# Download mapbox default style as tiles

Tags: tiles, tilemill, mapnik, mapbox

I need to have the tiles of a small city as PNGs. The style should be the same as in https://www.mapbox.com/editor/? Can I export the map there for a certain bounding box to tiles (or mbtiles)? I have setup a project but export to mbtiles or tiles does not seem to be available.

Or is it (as a workaround) possible to export just the mapbox default style in order to use this style with TileMill?

I have seen the [OSM Bright](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright) style, but I am not sure: Is this the same style as the default mapbox style?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MapBox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/#darwin), the desktop software used to design the MapBox Streets map you linked to.  (No, it's not exactly the same design as OSM Bright, but in MapBox Studio you can play around with the styles easily enough).

Export to print is pretty easy.  Create a new style project, link to OSM Bright2 (or whichever you choose), and click on the photo icon in the upper right corner.

Comment: Thx. 1st: Is the (very same) style as used for MapBox Streets map available for MapBox Studio? 2nd: Cannot find OSM Bright*2* style, do you have a link?

Comment: When you create a new style project in MapBox Studio, it should have four default styles, one of which is OSM Bright2.  But no, the OSM Bright style is not the same as MapBox Streets.  Couldn't find the carto styles posted anywhere--you could probably come close to replicating it w/ MapBox Studio, though.

Comment: Seems like the MapBox streets styles are proprietary and not available. https://www.mapbox.com/help/download-source-styles/